# RSpec - How to compound matchers raise_error and output.to_stdout?

Tags: ruby, rspec, thor

I've got a Thor based ruby CLI project to which I'm trying to add unit testing. It started as a pet project and is now rather large and important internally. Anyway, I have never really started unit testing, only grafted onto existing examples, and so I'm very much a noob when it comes to rspec.

I'm starting with a rather basic example, making sure that if I give it a file that doesn't exist, that it replies with an explanatory error and exits.

Here's the ways I have tried to compound them:

```
context 'with incorrect filename' do
  it 'should fail cleanly' do
    expect do
      subject.format('bad_file_name')
    end.to output('   ERROR  Unable to load file bad_file_name, exiting...').to_stdout.and raise_error(SystemExit)
  end
end
```

which works but doesn't capture the stdout properly [output here](http://pastebin.com/iUpZXTAZ).. also tried:

```
context 'with incorrect filename' do
  it 'should fail cleanly' do
    expect do
      expect do
        subject.format('fixtures/invalid.yaml')
      end.to output('   ERROR  Unable to load file bad_file_name, exiting...').to_stdout
    end.to raise_error(SystemExit)
  end
end
```

Which looks like it works, except (as this example shows) it's not actually testing the output because that output wouldn't match.

So what's the right way to check both an error that was raised and the output to stdout at the same time?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Maybe the `format` method doesn't output anything before exiting or the output goes to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: Can you provide a (failing) sample implementation for `format` so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I'll try and put something together. I tried chaging the output part to_stderr, and it still didn't work.  What's interesting is that if you look at the pastebin, it's definitely sending the output at lines 1 & 2. But it's not capturing it. I suspect it might be a quirk of how Thor's say_status funciton works. I see lots of examples using the "capture" example in Thor's [spec/helper](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/spec/helper.rb), but all of those examples don't seem to work with capturing errors and output at once.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: Nope, I've mostly been dealing with other issues, hopefully I'll be able to get back to this soon.

Answer (score 5):

this works for me

```
expect { whatever }.to output('stderr message').to_stderr
                   .and output(Regexp.new('stdout message')).to_stdout
                   .and raise_error('Error message')
```

Comment: If you need to ensure that `whatever` does *not* error, you can define a negated matcher: `RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_raise_error, :raise_error`, then chain that: `expect { whatever }.to output('msg').to_stderr.and not_raise_error()`.